# jquery .change() not triggering on select

Tags: javascript, jquery

why is my dropdown not triggering .change event and not getting the value of the option that was selected?

```
<select name="venture" id="venture" class="form-control">
    <option value="ph">Philippines</option>
    <option value="my">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="id">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="th">Thailand</option>
    <option value="vn">Vietnam</option>
    <option value="sg">Singapore</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#venture').change(function(){
         alert($(this).val());
    });
}
```

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j0xc79bm/

Comment: missing `)` at last.

Comment: You have a missing bracket and semi-colon closing your handler: `);`. Learn to check your browser console for errors.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j0xc79bm/1/ missing braces..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You havent closed ready function properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#venture').change(function(){
     alert($(this).val());
    });
 });
//^---- typo here
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m0y823vb/)**

Comment: oh geez, its so embarassing.. thanks man...

Comment: Wasn't this an awesome candidate for a comment? Furthermore, gaining upvotes on questions like this for someone with 20k reputation is ridiculous and shameful!